# Is batch script help allowed on superuser?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a lot of questions about .bat files (batch is a rudimentary programming language).

They're all about how their code does't work. I thought this would belong on stackoverflow, however I've flagged a few questions like this and I haven't seen any of them be migrated. Is batch file help allowed on SuperUser?

These questions aren't about running a batch file on a computer, it's about code in a batch file.

Comment: *"These questions aren't about running a batch file on a computer, it's about code in a batch file."* – I don't quite follow—where else would they run the files? Scripting questions for simple administrative tasks or anything a Super User would do are generally fine and on-topic here.

Comment: It's not about issue running batch files in general, it's about how the code of a specific batch file isn't working.

Comment: We tend to accept questions about simple scripting and automation.