# Are PowerShell questions, like batch questions, allowed on Super User?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Since PowerShell is often as system-based as batch is, I would assume it is allowed on Super User just like batch code. Am I correct?

Answer (score -4):

As I discovered from this question: [Are batch script questions allowed on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7736/are-batch-script-questions-allowed-on-super-user)

**Powershell is** allowed in SuperUser.